# Errors with gridview

Tags: c#, .net, grid

I had a `gridview` ASP.net that retrieves certain columns from an MS-SQL database. It was working fine, showing the data correctly and I was able to edit and delete as needed using the buttons that come with the gridview.

I now added a new column in the database and was updating my code.

I created a new `datasource` and I was now able to retrieve that column from the db. I had a problem not seeing the `edit` and `delete` in the gridview, but I was able to manage to show them using `AutoGenerateDeleteButton="true"` and `AutoGenerateEditButton="true"`.

However, when I press on the delete or the edit button, I get the below error.

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton'.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. `

Exception Details: System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton'.

Source Error: 

protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
LinkButton lnkbtn = ((LinkButton)e.CommandSource);
GridViewRow gvRow = (GridViewRow)(lnkbtn.NamingContainer);
HiddenField hdn_supplier = (HiddenField)gvRow.FindControl("hdn_supplier");
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: in the GridView1_RowCommand you are not testing that e is a linkbutton and then trying to reference its CommandSource. you might want to test e for type. if ((e as LinkButton) == null)

Answer (score 0):

this is a c# example from the working VB code that I have going on at the moment.  It looks like your missing your delete commend handler

```
protected void dgGlossaries_DeleteCommand(object source, System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGridCommandEventArgs e)
{
   dynamic rowToDelete = e.Item.ItemIndex;
   DataTable dt = (DataTable)Session["glossaries"];
   DataRow dr = dt.Rows(rowToDelete);
   dr.Delete();
   dgGlossaries.DataSource = dt;
}
```

this is the same example in VB that is working that should hopefully point you in the right direction if you get stuck with the c# example

```
Protected Sub dgGlossaries_DeleteCommand(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGridCommandEventArgs) Handles dgGlossaries.DeleteCommand
    Dim rowToDelete = e.Item.ItemIndex

    Dim dt As DataTable = DirectCast(Session("glossaries"), DataTable)
    Dim dr As DataRow = dt.Rows(rowToDelete)
    dr.Delete()

    dgGlossaries.DataSource = dt
    dgGlossaries.DataBind()
End Sub
```